# Multiprocessing with large HDF5 files

Tags: python-multiprocessing, hdf5, large-data

I have 5 HDF5 files that are 22 GB each. Each HDF5 file is a series of 4801 images that are 1920 by 1200 in size. I need to load the same frame number from each HDF5 file, get rid of some rogue pixels, average the stack of 5 images, and write a new HDF5 file with one processed image at each frame number. Because I can't load all 5 HDF5 files in at once without running out of RAM, I am only loading in chunks of images from each HDF5 file, putting 5 images for each frame number into a queue, processing the stack, and writing the resulting image to an HDF5 file. Right now I am using h5py to perform any reading/writing of HDF5 files.

I would like to know what the most computationally effective way is of working on chunked data? Right now, I am dedicating one processor to be the writer, then looping through some chunk size of data for which I create a number of consumers, put the data in a queue, wait for the consumers to be finished, then rinse and repeat until all of the images are processed. This means that every time the loop advances, it creates new consumer processes - I imagine there is some overhead in this. A sample of the code is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import os
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, JoinableQueue, cpu_count
import glob
import h5py
import numpy as np

'''Function definitions''' 

# The consumer function takes data off of the Queue
def consumer(inqueue,output):    
    # Run indefinitely
    while True:         
        # If the queue is empty, queue.get() will block until the queue has data
        all_data = inqueue.get()
        if all_data:
            #n is the index corresponding to the projection location 
            n, image_data = all_data
            #replace zingers with median and average stack 
            #Find the median for each pixel of the prefiltered image
            med = np.median(image_data,axis=0)
            #Loop through the image set
            for j in range(image_data.shape[0]):
                replicate = image_data[j,...]
                mask = replicate - med > zinger_level
                replicate[mask] = med[mask] # Substitute with median
                image_data[j,...] = replicate # Put data back in place
            out = np.mean(image_data,axis=0,dtype=np.float32).astype(np.uint16)
            output.put((n,out))
        else:
            break

#function for writing out HDF5 file        
def write_hdf(output,output_filename):
    #create output HDF5 file
    while True:
        args = output.get()
        if args:
            i,data = args
            with h5py.File(output_filename,'a') as fout:
                fout['Prefiltered_images'][i,...] = data
        else:
            break

def fprocess_hdf_stack(hdf_filenames,output_filename):
    file_list = []
    for fname in hdf_filenames:
        file_list.append(h5py.File(fname,'r'))
    #process chunks of data so that we don't run out of memory
    totsize = h5py.File(hdf_filenames[0],'r')['exchange']['data'].shape[0]
    data_shape =  h5py.File(hdf_filenames[0],'r')['exchange']['data'].shape
    fout.create_dataset('Prefiltered_images',data_shape,dtype=np.uint16)
    fout.close()
    ints = range(totsize)
    chunkSize= 100

    #initialize how many consumers we would like working 
    num_consumers = cpu_count()*2

    #Create the Queue objects
    inqueue = JoinableQueue()
    output = Queue()     

    #start process for writing HDF5 file
    proc = Process(target=write_hdf, args=(output,output_filename))
    proc.start()

    print("Loading %i images into memory..."%chunkSize)
    for i in range(0,totsize,chunkSize):
        time0 = time.time()
        chunk = ints[i:i+chunkSize]
        data_list = []
        #Make a list of the HDF5 datasets we are reading in
        for files in file_list:
            #shape is (angles, rows, columns)
            data_list.append(files['exchange']['data'][chunk,...])
        data_list = np.asarray(data_list)
        print("Elapsed time to load images %i-%i is %0.2f minutes." %(chunk[0],chunk[-1],(time.time() - time0)/60))

        consumers = []       

        #Create consumer processes
        for i in range(num_consumers):
            p = Process(target=consumer, args=(inqueue,output))
            consumers.append(p)
            p.start()

        for n in range(data_list.shape[1]):
            #Feed data into the queue
            inqueue.put((chunk[n],data_list[:,n,...]))

        #Kill all of the processes when everything is finished    
        for i in range(num_consumers):
            inqueue.put(None)

        for c in consumers:
            c.join()
        print("Elapsed time to process images %i-%i is %0.2f minutes." %(chunk[0],chunk[-1],(time.time() - time0)/60))

    time.sleep(1)
    output.put(None)
    proc.join()     

    #Close the input HDF5 files.
    for hdf_file in file_list:
        hdf_file.close()
    print("Input HDF5 files closed.") 
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    start_time = time.time()
    raw_images_filenames = glob.glob(raw_images_dir + raw_images_basename)
    tempname = os.path.basename(raw_images_filenames[0]).split('.')[0]
    tempname_split = tempname.split('_')[:-1]
    output_filename = output_dir+'_'.join(tempname_split) + '_Prefiltered.hdf5'
    fprocess_hdf_stack(raw_images_filenames,output_filename)
    print("Elapsed time is %0.2f minutes" %((time.time() - start_time)/60))
```

I don't think my bottleneck is actually in the loading of the images. It is in initializing the consumers and carrying out the processing on the 5 images per each frame number. I've played around with taking the consumer function out of the for loop, but I don't know how to put a memory cap on this so that I don't run out of RAM. Thanks!